# Criterion for Spontaneity for Closed Systems at Constant Volume and Pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

For a closed system at constant temperature and volume, the criterion for spontaneity is $dA < 0$. However, for a system at constant composition, the total differential of $A$ is given by
$$dA = -PdV -SdT.$$
This seems to imply that $dA = 0$ for a system at constant volume, temperature, and composition. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy) for Helmholtz Free Energy claims that this relationship holds even for non-spontaneous processes. The derivation of $A$ as criterion for spontaneity at constant volume and temperature is
$$dA = dU - TdS - SdT = \delta q - TdS + \delta w - SdT.$$
If we consider only $PdV$ work, we obtain
$$dA = \delta q - TdS - PdV - SdT$$
and at constant $T$ and $V$, we get
$$dA = \delta q -TdS.$$
The criterion $dA <0$ for spontaneous processes then follows from the Clausius inequality. These two equations seem to be contradictory, so I was hoping someone could explain how this can be reconciled. Thank you so much!

**Clarification:**
The way I derived the $dA = -PdV - SdT$ for an arbitrary process is as follows:

For a function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the complete differential of $f$ is
$$df = f_1 dx_1 + f_2 dx_2 + \dots + f_n dx_n$$
where
$$f_i = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)_{x_j \: j\neq i}.$$
Consider the function
$$g = f - f_1 x_1.$$
The differential of $g$ is
$$dg = df - f_1 dx_1 -x_1df_1$$
so that
$$dg = -x_1 df_1 + f_2 dx_2 + \dots + f_n dx_n.$$
Now, applying this to the special case of internal energy $U(S,V)$, if we define
$$A = U - \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V} S = U - TS$$
then the above implies that
$$dA = -SdT - PdV$$
since
$$dU = TdS - PdV.$$

Comment: Consider review of search results for [site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org thermodynamics closed system spontaneity criteria](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Alibretexts.org+thermodynamics+closed+system+spontaneity+criteria)

Comment: Provide you reasoning what you think they are contradictory. as dS >= dq/T,  dq - TdS <=0.  0 for reversible processes, <0 for spontaneous ones.

Comment: For a spontaneous process at constant temperature and volume, the fact that $dQ < TdS$ implies that $dA < 0$ with a strict inequality. However, the fact that $dA = - PdV -SdT$ seems to imply that for any constant volume and temperature (and constant composition), we have $dA = 0$ since $dV = 0$ and $dT = 0$. This is the main source of my confusion.

Comment: dA=-p.dV -SdT is derived with assumption dq=T.dS, i.e. for reversible, non spontaneous changes, so TdS and -TdS mutually cancel.

Comment: The link I provided to the Wikipedia article states that this relationship holds for non-reversible processes as well. That is where I am confused

Comment: dU=TdS - p.dV only if dQ=TdS what is true only for reversible processes where dS=dQ/T

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = U -TS$$
$$\mathrm{d}A = \delta Q - p\mathrm{d}V + \delta W_\text{nonexp} - T\mathrm{d}S - S\mathrm{d}T$$
$$dS \ge \delta Q/T \implies T\mathrm{d}S \ge \delta Q $$
Assuming $\delta W_\text{nonexp}=0$:
$$\mathrm{d}A = \delta Q - p\mathrm{d}V - T\mathrm{d}S - S\mathrm{d}T$$
As $T\mathrm{d}S \ge \delta Q$:
$$\mathrm{d}A \le T\mathrm{d}S - p\mathrm{d}V - T\mathrm{d}S - S\mathrm{d}T$$
$$\mathrm{d}A \le - p\mathrm{d}V - S\mathrm{d}T$$

Comment: This makes sense. Does the derivation of $dA = -PdV - SdT$ using Legendre transformations assume reversibility? I thought it holds in general

Comment: Because the statement that "the natural variables of A are V and T" seems to imply that A(V,T) is constant for any process at constant V and T so that dA = 0

Comment: It uses the A definition, the Clausius inequality TdS>=dQ and ordinary mathematical operations. // AFAIK, the Leg. tr. was used and the source for decision of the way to define A and G as state functions.

Comment: Aren't all of those true in general? I don't see why that derivation is only valid for reversible processes

Comment: But I as a chemist  am not familiar with Legendre transformations by the name, rather just Legendre orthogonal polynoms.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added a clarification that details the derivation I used and this process is known as Legendre transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation

Comment: Thank you for your help! One quick clarification with your answer: if $dA = -pdV - SdT$ is only true for reversible processes, why is it true that the natural variables of $A$ are $V$ and $T$ so that $A$ is a function of $V$ and $T$ only?

Comment: The point is, A is not function only of V and T. If the system underwent chem. reaction, phase transition or other spontaneous process, A decreased even at constant V and T.